# Sending output to external process

Tags: java, vlc, outputstream

For some reason, I'm having problems sending output to a process that I've created in Java. The external process is running in a command prompt, and the peculiar thing is that I can click that, type, hit enter, and I'll get output from the program. It addition my program can read all the output coming from the program, it just can't send anything to it.

Anyways, here is the relevant code I'm using that just isn't working...

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder builder=new ProcessBuilder(args);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    final Process p=builder.start();
    // Process has been created and is running
    try {
        String b="";
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        final BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
        new Thread(){public void run(){
            // This thread will periodically send "get_time" to the process to get an update on its progress
            while(true)
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    p.exitValue();
                    // p.exitValue() only works when process has ended, so normal code goes in the catch block
                    output.close();
                    break;
                    // Leave the infinite loop if the program has closed
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(OvMusicUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    break;
                    // Leave the infinite loop if we tried closing our output stream, but it was already closed
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(OvMusicUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Outputted: get_time");
                        output.write("get_time" + System.lineSeparator());
                        output.flush();
                        // Give the process some input
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(OvMusicUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }}.start();
        while((b = input.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(new Time(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString() + " " + b);
            // Log all output the process gives
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(OvMusicUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    // More code here
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(OvMusicUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

If necessary, I can give an example command and the name of the external program being run so you can try it yourself...

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is an example of what's passed into the ProcessBuilder: `Arrays.asList("VLC\vlc.exe", "-Irc", "-vvv", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfeys7Jfnx8", "--sout", "file/ogg:Untitled 1.ogg", "--play-and-exit", "--rc-quiet")`. The only difference is I use absolute paths instead of relative paths. The program is VLC Media Player 2.0.7.

Comment: Are you redirecting `stdout` of another program to your Java code?

Comment: As a side note, you code will be both cleaner and much faster if you use a `private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(name)` class field.

Comment: Always go ahead and post useful information such as what external program you're calling.

Comment: @PM77-1 That's the only program I'm running, so there is no other program besides this one I'm calling.

Comment: @chrylis Good tip, I'll begin doing that with all errors. In addition, I edited in the program I'm calling above with its arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a few problems. First, you generally should **not** use exceptions for your regular control flow: it's expensive, it's difficult to read, and it makes handling actual errors more difficult. It's generally better to spawn another `Thread` that calls `p.waitFor()` and signals your main thread to complete, such as with `wait`/`notify`.

Also, your construction with the infinite loop and using `break` instead of `return` will make your code more difficult to debug; instead, use a `Timer`.

It looks like the output to your external program probably is working correctly but that the problem is just with reading its output.  The program may be buffering its own output or may be detecting that it's not being run interactively and behaving differently.